# Why is there a Force acting on the travellers who were at a higher speed during space travel in The Expanse series

Tags: novel, the-expanse-2015

Sorry guyz my question was not clear. In other movies like Star Wars, Star Trek and similar movies where they travel at light speed or more than that, those movies never showed any kind of force exerted on the astronauts. They just jump to hyperspeed/warpspeed and come to halt their ships easily without any affects on their bodies. In Expanse, light speed technology was not mentioned but those ships did have some high speed technology, may be lesser than light speed. While the ships move at such speeds a force was applied on the people traveling in it and a white liquid was injected in their bodies to keep them awake. My question is If there is no gravity in space then how come humans felt a force which made them to pass out like Chrisjen Avasarala passed out when she traveled in Razorback ship. 
Does fast moving space ships in space affect humans and hence a liquid was used to keep them awake. I need this theory to be answered. Hope you are able to understand me now.

My original question for reference: In The Expanse series it was shown that the people inside Rosinate and Razorback had to be injected with some liquid in order to stay awake during the ship travelled at a higher speed than usual. Why was that liquid needed if space doesn't exert any force on human body. Please can you explain what kind of force was affecting the people travelling in space in these series. I also want to know if that was due to the artificial gravity that the ships produced.

Comment: You've already mentioned g-forces in your question title. That's what

Comment: Yes. However I dont know if my guess is correct about G force. I mentioned it because i dont know what is the force shown in the series. My main question is they could have switched the artificial gravity off and then travel at higher speed. So why they needed the liquid to stay awake?

Comment: Your question really doesn't make that at all clear.

Comment: there's no artificial gravity in The Expanse. There's gravity in proximity to mass (palnets, suns) gravity due to acceleration and gravity due to centrifugal force.

Comment: Why has this question been closed? It's sci-fi (albeit hard sci-fy) and the author clearly doesn't understand some elements of physics makig this a very valid question.

Comment: Space doesn't exert any force on human body.

The crew in an accelerating ship (accelerating due to thrust), experience gravity.

The greater the thrust, the faster the acceleration. The greater the acceleration, the greater the gavitity. This is known as "gravity due to acceleration".

The liquid is not to keep them awake. it is a cocktail of chemicals that will help the body survive the effects of high G thrust and manouvers  and help prevent a stroke.

Comment: @KerrAvon because it’s not really clear what they’re asking considering they appear to have answered it themselves in the title.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot  - Oh, I see - thank you. But I don't think the author understands it so doesn't recognize the answer in the title.

Comment: @Musafir Mrinal Samant  - Have you ever been in a car that accelerates very quickly? you get thrown back in your seat, right?. This is because you become heavier in the direction of  motion and this is gravity due to acceleration.

Comment: @KerrAvon - My issue here is that OP is asking a bunch of different questions, some answerable, some hard science, some that really just don't make very much sense at all.

Comment: For the record, Star Wars and Star Trek are both extremely unrealistic depictions of space travel.  Star Wars exclusively uses Lucas physics rather than actual physics, and Star Trek has improbable hypothetical technologies such as "inertial dampeners" which is the only thing preventing the crew being pretty much instantly killed by g-forces.

Comment: In the world of *The Expanse*, they don’t even have artificial gravity. It’s more realistic than other sci fi, often called “hard sci fi”, as opposed to “soft sci fi” like Star Wars and Star Trek. The force acting on the crews in *The Expanse* is the force of thrust provided by the engines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Acceleration causes significant force on the human body**.  This force is actually not something we can survive for long, although we've also not really had the chance to test the human body's reaction to long-term acceleration like that.  Humans black out around [4-6 g](https://hypertextbook.com/facts/1998/PhillipAndriyevsky.shtml) if that acceleration has been acting for only a few seconds and the person is not in some sort of pressure suit.

In The Expanse, ships are limited to accelerate at around 1g for safety. Amazingly this cuts the earth to Mars travel time down to a few days (including time to turn around and brake) and provides artificial gravity for the trip. If ships are in a huge hurry, such as in EP. 1 where the Canterbury needs to stop and change direction to respond to the distress call they receive, they need to under go a "high g" maneuver. These maneuvers require extreme acceleration beyond 1g for longer periods of time, so the crew uses that drug cocktail to be able to handle it.  The highest acceleration we see in season 2 is 18g, which is described by the crew as being fatal even with the drug if done for a long time. The exact time was never given, though.

Comment: I downvoted because you've answered a clearly off-topic question. Also, you've done so with no reference to the question's fictional universe.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  Would it be better if I modified the answer to include a reference to acceleration in the Expanse itself, or is the question closed and therefore it's pointless?

Comment: Frankly, I'd wait for OP to revise it. Trying to play "catchee monkey" with a question that needs editing to bring it on-topic is a thankless task because he could radically alter it, making your (revised) answer worthless.

Comment: Thanks Michael, Valorum and others of looking in to this matter.  Michael please include a reference to speed in the Expanse series.  I have edited my question and put in more details I hope you may able to understand what i want to ask.

Comment: Also, from a physics standpoint, acceleration does not cause any forces. Forces cause acceleration. It’s the force of thrust that is accelerating the ships and the attached chairs into the backs of the passengers, and the property of inertia that makes that push transmitted from the engines through the ship to the bodies via the chairs (called the normal force, usually) stressful on the bodies.

Comment: The only thing I would add is that "in other movies like Star Wars, Star Trek and similar movies where they travel at light speed or more than that, those movies never showed any kind of force exerted on the astronauts" because they aren't travelling really fast - they are warping space to make the trip shorter and are travelling at a slow, constant speed through the shorter distance.